# \newcommand with one or two argument

Tags: conditionals, xparse

I am trying to define a shorthand command for making some references faster to write. As of now the best I can do is

```
\newcommand{\apologien}[2]{#1\textit{A} #2}
\newcommand{\apo}[1]{\apologien{1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\apoz}[1]{\apologien{2}{#1}}
```

Is works well for e.g. `\apo{65.1}`. However, if want to reference a hole text and not only specific chapter or verse i would use e.g. `\apo`. This would leave me with an unwanted trailing space.

Among other things have I tried the following:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\apologien}{mo}
  {%
    #1\textit{A}\IfValueT{#2}{ {#2}}
  }
```

or

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\apologien}[2]{#1\textit{A}\ifthenelse{\isundefined{#2}}{}{ #2}}
```

or

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\apologien}[2][]{#1\textit{A}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{ #2}}
```

I finally got it to work for \apo{} with

```
\usepackage{trimspaces}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\apologien}[2]{\trim@spaces{#1\textit{A} #2}}
\makeatother
```

However, I would really like to know, why my other attempts did not work.

Example document:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[
        fontsize=12pt,
        paper=a4,
        titlepage,
        twoside,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{trimspaces}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\apologien}[2]{\trim@spaces{#1\textit{A} #2}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\apo}[1]{\apologien{1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\apoz}[1]{\apologien{2}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
Commmand & Wanted\\
\hline
\apologien{1}.        & 1\textit{A}.\\
\apologien{1}{}.      & 1\textit{A}.\\
\apologien{1}{65.1}.  & 1\textit{A} 65.1.\\
\apo{65.1}.           & 1\textit{A} 65.1.\\
\apo.                 & 1\textit{A}.\\
\apo{}.               & 1\textit{A}.\\
\apoz{5.1}.           & 2\textit{A} 5.1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, it would be helpful to have a compilable document and not just fragments.... I don't understand what you really want to achieve here. I also don't understand why you're not using a `\label-\ref` approach

Comment: What is wrong with `\newcommand{\apo}[2][2]{#1\textit{A} #2}`?

Comment: @marmot if you paste that command into the example document, it clearly gives the wrong result.

Comment: @rlp Sure, I know. I posted this just to tell you that there is a simple way to have an optional argument with a predefined value.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is that when you rewrote your macros so that they used optional arguments you didn't change your macros so they they used optional arguments.

To be more explicit, if you define

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\apologien}{mo}
  {%
    #1\textit{A}\IfValueT{#2}{ {#2}}
  }
```

then you have to use `\apologien` with an optional argument so that the definitions of `\apo` and `\apoz` must also be changed to

```
\newcommand{\apo}[1]{\apologien{1}[#1}]}
\newcommand{\apoz}[1]{\apologien{2}[#1]}
```

You actually have a similar problem in your "now working" MWE because you use `\apo.` and `\apo{}`. The first of these expands to `\apologien{1}{.}` and the second expands to `\apologien{1}{}`, so it may be accidental that you get what you want. If you want this syntax to work then `\apo` and `\apoz` must also accept optional arguments.

As far as I can see you do not need to use the [trimspaces](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/trimspaces) package and can instead use:

```
\documentclass[
        fontsize=12pt,
        paper=a4,
        titlepage,
        twoside,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\apologien{ mo }{#1\textit{A}\IfValueT{#2}{\space #2}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\apo}{o}{\IfValueTF{#1}{\apologien{1}[#1]}{\apologien{1}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\apoz}{o}{\IfValueTF{#1}{\apologien{2}[#1]}{\apologien{1}}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline
    Commmand & Wanted\\
    \hline
    \apologien{1}.        & 1\textit{A}.\\
    \apologien{1}{}.      & 1\textit{A}.\\
    \apologien{1}[65.1].  & 1\textit{A} 65.1.\\
    \apo[65.1].           & 1\textit{A} 65.1.\\
    \apo.                 & 1\textit{A}.\\
    \apo{}.               & 1\textit{A}.\\
    \apoz[5.1].           & 2\textit{A} 5.1\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Certainly, this produces your expected output:

[image]

Note, however, that you need to use optional arguments when they are expected!

One final comment: usual practice in latex is to put the optional arguments first. Of course, you do not need to do this but for me at least it is more natural to write:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\apologien{ om }{#2\textit{A}\IfValueT{#1}{\space #1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\apo}{o}{\IfValueTF{#1}{\apologien[#1]{1}}{\apologien{1}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\apoz}{o}{\IfValueTF{#1}{\apologien[#1]{2}}{\apologien{1}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yur special need is to distinguish between `\apo{something}` and `\apo` where the `{` does not follows. Then `\futurelet` TeX primitive needs to be used:

```
\def\apo  {1{\it A}\futurelet\next\apoA}
\def\apoz {2{\it A}\futurelet\next\apoA}
\def\apoA{\ifx\next\bgroup \space \fi}

Test:

\apo {65.1}, \apo.

\apoz {65.1}, \apoz.

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

## Analysis

Let's consider the code

```
\newcommand{\apologien}[2]{#1\textit{A} #2}
\newcommand{\apo}[1]{\apologien{1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\apoz}[1]{\apologien{2}{#1}}
```

If you call `\apo.` or `\apo{}.` like in your example, argument `#1` is the period in the former case and empty in the latter, resulting in

```
\apologien{1}{.}
\apologien{1}{}.
```

and you eventually get, in both cases

```
1\textit{A} .
```

## Proposed solution

Since the chapter and verse part seems to be optional, it makes sense to treat it as such:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\apologien}{mo}{%
  #1\textit{A}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{~#2}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\apo}{}{\apologien{1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\apoz}{}{\apologien{2}}
```

and you should call the commands like

```
\apologien{1}.
\apologien{1}[65.1].
\apo[65.1].
\apo.
\apoz[5.1].
```

with a consistent syntax. Even if you use `\apo{}` (maybe for protecting a following space), the result will be as specified.

## Alternative (but not recommended) solution

Just for completeness, but this is a method I don't recommend at all, you *could* do

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\apologien}{mg}{%
  #1\textit{A}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{~#2}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\apo}{}{\apologien{1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\apoz}{}{\apologien{2}}
```

and change the brackets `[...]` into `{...}` in the code above. However, `\apo{}` would still lead to an unwanted space and some more work would be needed

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\apologien}{mg}
 {
  #1\textit{A}
  \IfValueT { #2 } { \tl_if_blank:nF { #2 } { \nobreakspace #2 } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```